# Why is GCP Cloud Build failing systematically and how to fix it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We recently started having systematic failure of GCP Cloud Build for one of our projects, with this message:

```
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": Restoring data for SBOM from previous image
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: retrieving launch SBOM layer: GET https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.<our-project>.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:(...)?access_token=REDACTED: unexpected status code 404 Not Found: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: eu.artifacts.<our-project>.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:(...)</Details></Error>
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:python_20230306_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

The same deployment onto another GCP project was still successful and nothing had changed in our deployment settings.  After several days, the problem did not vanish, it seemed we would never again deploy any new version to this project.

[The issue was posted on GCP's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273299799), and acknowledged as 'bug', but after several days it seemed it would not be fixed any time soon, with a low priority and low severity, although it was truly a blocking issue.

It took us much efforts and groping around to find a workaround that fixes the issue for good, although it does not fix the root cause.  In case someone encounters the same GCP Cloud Build bug, I will post our workaround here.

Answer (score 3):

Run an `gcloud app deploy` with the `--no-cache option`. Doing this just once (once per service if there are many services) will solve the problem, the subsequent deploys will be successful without the `--no-cache` option.

It seems cloud build had somehow made up some erroneous cache data that made it fail systematically and the `--no-cache` is the way to reset things.

I do think the issue deserves some more work from Google to be solved for real, because it will probably happen again to someone else.

Comment: Thank you this method works for me , I was using gCloud version 421.0.0